# Python Eve: 412 Precondition Failed on PATCH

Tags: python, eve

I have a Python Eve application with the following relevant code:

```
def handle_user_update(request, lookup):
if request and request.data:
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    users = app.data.driver.db['users']
    user = users.find_one(ObjectId(lookup['_id']))
    if user and user['activation_code'] == data['activation_code']:
        app.data.update('users', ObjectId(lookup['_id']), {'active':True})
    else:
        abort(403)

app = Eve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.on_pre_PATCH_users += handle_user_update
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Field is defined:

```
'active': {
    'type': 'boolean',
    'readonly': True,
    'default': False
},
'activation_code': {
    'type': 'string',
    'readonly': True
}
```

I am sending a PATCH request:

```
If-Match:       c8f9351a7527f8aa1db191fe85017df1dbca961f
{"activation_code": "8f775627d1144dbd8367778e8680ed58"}
```

I got the If-Match from the ETag of a GET request sent immediately prior to this PATCH. The app.data.update method executes and the data is updated as expected, however I get response **412 PRECONDITION FAILED**. Why? What should I do in order to get **200 OK**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your `users` document is being updated is that you are hooking your callback function to a [Pre-Request Event](http://python-eve.org/features#pre-request-event-hooks). Those are raised every time a request is received and **before it is processed**. In your case you probably want to hook your callback to a [Database Event](http://python-eve.org/features#database-event-hooks). Database events are only raised if a request has been validated and accepted, **immediately before a document is sent to the database**. In your case I would hook my function to `on_update` which is fired on validated `PATCH` request. Doing that would prevent your code from acting on the database if the original request is going be rejected, something you probably don't want to happen.

On the reason why `412 PRECONDITION FAILED` is raised well... on `PATCH` requests that's only returned if ETag don't match so make sure you are providing the right one. Also on which Eve version are you?

UPDATE
On v0.4, if you `users` is also the target of request, then the ETag changes as soon as you perform your custom write (document representation changes) so that would explain while you get a `412` later on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am running Eve-0.4. I am sure the ETag matches as I copied it from the GET response. Can I still hook up on Database Event even if my field is defined as read-only? That's the reason why I am using the pre-request event.

Comment: Oh yes `readonly` only applies on data coming from request payload. The field is not readonly on the database itself so you can update it however you want.

Comment: I updated my answer with the likely reason why you are getting a `412` on v0.4.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up changing my design, by removing the 'readonly' from the fields and enforcing the check on DB record insert & update.